Map of 32 Tags of CogSci.SE
Lastly I'm not that active on this site, but I made a map of CogSci.SE, basing on tag co-occurrences.

Some more description e.g. on a respective post on meta.math.SE.
The project is on GitHub: https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki (feel invited to tweak the plot to your taste).
I hope you like it! (For site promotion or just some insight.) :)
And before anyone asks, colors are for graph communities (groups of nodes which have a lot of connections between each other). 

Ooooh, purrrrdy! Thanks Piotr!

This is cool -- but how did you get the data? CogSci.SE is still in beta, meaning its info isn't in Data.SE!

It makes it harder and slower, but it is possible to use SE API to harvest all questions. The instruction is here: https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange#beta-sites-and-other-tags

@PiotrMigdal Would you like me to get you a CSV of the relevant data? I could send it via a mod here, or I could email it to you directly.

@Aarthi What do you mean by "relevant data"? But sure, why not, I will see what's there (e-mail preferred; or if >1MB then Dropbox link or sth, please).

No problem! Could you please email aarthi at stackexchange dot com for me, and I'll send you the CSV!

Thanks for doing that @Aarthi!

I am really late on this, just saw it. Awesome!

I made an interactive version of the above, with always up-to-date data, TagOverflow.
You can check tag grouping - i.e. for the sake of eliminating synonyms or poorly-defined tags.
Code and a more detailed description is on Github.

